# How to trigger the edit command on a RowSelect event of a Telerik grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik Grid on a MVC3 project with Razor layout engine with the popUp edit mode working fine. Here is the grid code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid-moedas")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(m => m.ID))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.Nome);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Simbolo);
        columns.Bound(m => m.ExtensoNoSingular);
        columns.Bound(m => m.ExtensoNoPlural);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
        });   
    })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
        {
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("AjaxGrid", "Moeda");
            dataBinding.Ajax().Update("AjaxEdit", "Moeda");
        })
    .Sortable()
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable(paging =>
            paging.Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndInput)
    )
    .Footer(true)
    .ClientEvents(events => events            
            .OnRowSelect("onRowSelect")
    )
    .Selectable()
)
```

I wanna two things:

1. Hide the buttons generated for each row on the grid
2. Call the edit command on the OnRowSelect event, so the editing popUp form will be called in response to the user click on a row.

   function onRowSelect(e) {
           //how to call edit command for e.row???
           return false;
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<script>
   function onRowSelect(e) {
       var grid = $(this).data("tGrid");
       grid.editRow($(e.row));
   }
</script>
```

Comment: it works and now I see my mistake. Instead of grid.editRow($(e.row)), I was trying grid.editRow(e.row).

Answer (score 0):

I can't easily try this (I don't have the Telerik controls), but is this of any use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnRowClick(sender, args) {
        var masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
        masterTable.fireCommand("Edit", args.get_itemIndexHierarchical())
    }
</script>
```

Taken from here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/grid-edit-on-row-select.aspx#1405657